# Is it possible to add a custom class to any of the SVG DOM elements auto-generated by DC?

Tags: dc.js

Suppose DC.js is used to create a composite chart consisting of 3 line charts.

```
var compositeChart = dc.compositeChart(domId);
var lineChart1 = dc.lineChart(compositeChart);
var lineChart2 = dc.lineChart(compositeChart);
var lineChart3 = dc.lineChart(compositeChart);
compositeChart.compose([lineChart1, lineChart2, lineChart3]);
```

The resulting SVG looks something like

```
<svg>
    <g>
        <g class="sub _0">
            <g class="chart-body">
                <g class="stack-list">
                    <g class="stack _0">
                        <path class="line">...</p>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g class="sub _1">...</g>
        <g class="sub _2">...</g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Is it possible to add a custom class to any of the SVG DOM elements auto-generated by DC? So that the resulting svg would look something like

```
<svg>
    <g>
        <g class="sub _0">
            <g class="chart-body myLine1ClassNameGoesHereeeeee">
                <g class="stack-list">
                    <g class="stack _0">
                        <path class="line">...</p>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g class="sub _1">...</g>
        <g class="sub _2">...</g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lineChart1.select('.chart-body').classed('myLine1ClassNameGoesHereeeeee', true);
```

I believe that should work.